# QtConcurrent - grouped calls to same function in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, multiprocessing, qtconcurrent

I would like to know best practice for calling same function generating a random point (random coordinates) several time in a thread. Actually, I already implemented parallelized calls for this function, say randomPoint(). Now, I would like to try whether it improves not to create a thread for each call, but to run calculations in exactly the number of available threads. I calculates

```
QThreadPool pool;
int freeThreads_ = pool.maxThreadCount();

int iterPerThread_ = ((N-m)%freeThreads_ ==0) ? (N-m)/freeThreads_ : (N-m)/(freeThreads_-1) ;
```

For me, 8 threads are available. I have 2000 similar calculations to perform. I thus want to run 8 threads with 2000/8 calculations per thread.

But then I don't know what is the best way to implement QtConcurrent call. For now, I write

```
QFuture<double**> futurRand_ = QtConcurrent::run(randomPoint(),m_lower,m_upper);
```

and then futurRand_.result();
I adapted method randomPoint(), initially returning a simgle point (double*) so that it can return a double**, a set of 2000/8 points.

but I saw an alternative with QConcurent::map(). Is there a more efficient way? with QThread?

Your experience with multithread in Qt is welcome!

Regards.

-- EDIT :
To make it more precise: map has the signature

```
 QFuture<void> QtConcurrent::map ( Sequence & sequence, MapFunction function )
```

or altinatively takes an iterator as one of its arguments. However, I call here a function that is called each time on the same instance, *this*. How to proceed? What other convenient ways does exist ?

Comment: Are those 2000 iterations independant of each other like in a loop for example?

Comment: ok, are you bound to QT? Such loops can easily be paralized with parallel libraries like intel tbb or microsoft ppl.

Comment: @bamboon thanks. yes, I am restricted to Qt in a this project that involves lots of other programmers bound to Qt : ) Any idea?

Comment: `QtConcurent` seems OK now, when in `Qt 4.8` Qt fixed their slow mutexes. Use it. I also cannot understand, what issues you get with `map`? What do you mean by "call here a function that is called each time on the same instance, this"?